# PHP - OOP new class with agrument?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Dictionary {
    private $translations = array();
    private $dictio;
    private $type;

    function __construct( $type, DictionaryIO $dictio ) {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->dictio = $dictio;
    }

    // ...
}

$en = new Dictionary( "En", new DictionaryIO() );
$en->dictio = null;
```

i saw something like above code. Someone can tell me effective of line code

```
$en = new Dictionary( "En", new DictionaryIO() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone can tell me effective of line code

A new object of the class `Dictionary` is created. The two arguments are passed to the constructor function, which stores them internally.

The `DictionaryIO` prefix in front of `DictionaryIO $dictio` is a so called [type hint](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) that forces the second parameter to be an object of the class `DictionaryIO`.

The last line

```
$en->dictio = null;
```

will not work because `$dictio` is private.